# Can you call Eclipse’s java formatter from the command line?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to call the Eclipse Java formatting engine (which is also apparently used by the Red Hat VSCode Java extension) from the command line?

Comment: I'd use [astyle](https://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can Artistic Style read the settings of the Eclipse formatter? And does it understand Java language feature of Java 17 and higher (records, pattern matching for instanceof, etc.). It seems to be no longer maintained.

Comment: You can do this from maven too: https://code.revelc.net/formatter-maven-plugin/format-mojo.html

Comment: Let me know if you're not satisfied and I might have a suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can run the Eclipse formatter from the command line using an [Eclipse Java IDE package](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) or the [Eclipse SDK](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.25-202208311800/#EclipseSDK). See [Eclipse help: Java development user guide > Tasks > Using the Formatter Application](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-231.htm):

```
eclipse -noSplash -vm <path to virtual machine> -data <workspace> -application org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter [ OPTIONS ] <files>
```

Comment: This appears to open the Eclipse IDE splash screen. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @schuelermine Yes, with `-noSplash`. You might also use `eclipsec` (`c` for command line) instead of the `eclipse` executable.

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse formatter in VS Code and had it save the settings as `.vscode/java-formatter.xml`. I'm pretty sure the same thing should work with Eclipse itself as long as you can locate / export the settings.

This is how the settings file contents look like for reference:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<profiles version="20">
    <profile kind="CodeFormatterProfile" name="JavaConventions" version="20">
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_ellipsis" value="insert" />
        <setting
            id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_enum_declarations"
            value="insert" />
...
```

Then you can use Spotless with Maven in a really convenient way, it has commands to check or format all files.

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
      <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.40.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!--
        https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/main/plugin-maven#-spotless-keep-your-code-spotless-with-maven

        Usage:
        mvn spotless:apply
        mvn spotless:check
        -->
        <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
        <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <java>
            <eclipse>
              <file>${project.basedir}/.vscode/java-formatter.xml</file>
            </eclipse>
          </java>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```